# $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ distinct positive integer-valued vectors $(x_1,x_2, ... x_r)$...

Tags: probability-theory

**Proposition**: There are $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$  distinct positive integer-valued vectors $(x_1,x_2, ... x_r)$ satisfying the equation

$$x_1+x_2 + ... x_r = n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_i\gt0$$

**Textbook**: To obtain  the number of nonnegative (as opposed to positive) solutions, note that the number of *nonnegative* solutions of $x_1+x_2 + ... x_r = n$ is the same as the number of *positive* solutions of $y_1 + ... + y_r = n+r$, as seen by letting $y_i = x_i +1,i = 1,...,r$.

**Question**: I see that  $y_1 + ... + y_r = x_1+x_2 + ... x_r + \sum_{i=1}^{r}1 = n+r$, but why must the number of *nonnegative* solutions of $x_1+x_2 + ... x_r = n$  be the same as the number of *positive* solutions of $y_1 + ... + y_r = n+r$? And what exactly is a nonnegative *vector* solution, is it a vector such that no scalar is less than zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-negative vector solution is merely a solution where the variables $x_1, \dots, x_r$ are non-negative and written as components of a vector, i.e. $(x_1, \dots, x_r)$.

For convenience, call $x_1 + \dots + x_r = n$ equation $(1)$ and $y_1 + \dots + y_r = n + r$ equation $(2)$.

Let $(x_1, \dots, x_r)$ be a non-negative solution to the equation $(1)$. Setting $y_i = x_i + 1$, we find that $(y_1, \dots, y_r)$ is a positive solution to the equation $(2)$. Suppose now that $(x_1', \dots, x_r')$ is another non-negative vector solution to equation $(1)$, then setting $y_i' = x_i' + 1$, we find that $(y_1', \dots, y_r')$ is a positive solution to equation $(2)$. Furthermore, $(y_1', \dots, y_r') = (y_1, \dots, y_r)$ if and only if $(x_1', \dots, x_r') = (x_1, \dots, x_r)$. That is, distinct non-negative solutions to equation $(1)$ gives distinct positive solutions to equation $(2)$. Hence, we have at least as many solutions to equation $(2)$ as we do to equation $(1)$. Said slightly differently, the map $(x_1, \dots, x_r) \mapsto (y_1, \dots, y_r)$ is injective, hence the cardinality of the codomain is at least the cardinality of the domain.

Conversely, you can (and should) show that the map which associates to any positive solution $(y_1, \dots, y_r)$ of equation $(2)$ the non-negative solution $(x_1, \dots, x_r)$ of equation $(1)$ is also injective. Therefore the number of positive solutions to equation $(1)$ is at least as many as the number of non-negative solutions to equation $(2)$. Combining with the previous paragraph, we see that the number of solutions is the same. That is, both maps are bijections, i.e. $(x_1, \dots, x_r) \leftrightarrow (y_1, \dots, y_r)$ is a one-to-one correspondence.